# how to stop sublime from trimming white space when copy/paste?

Tags: sublimetext2

It seems that sublime is trimming copied text from any white spaces, so when I try to copy/paste formated text the format breaks. Eg I have:

```
   bla
   blub
   blab
```

I then copy the middle line, with white spaces and line break and insert it, I expect (and get in every other text editor I ever used)

```
   bla
   blub
   blub
   blab
```

but I get

```
   bla
blub   blub
   blab
```

So, is there a way to get the expected behavior from sublime? I searched for a solution many times, without any result so far, and it drives me crazy.

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you are selecting, copying, and pasting the text (mouse actions, keyboard shortcuts, menu options, etc.)? It looks like you're not actually selecting either the initial white space or the final newline character. One shortcut you may be interested in is `Ctrl-Shift-D`, which duplicates the current line/selection. Put your cursor anywhere in the line you want to duplicate, hit the key combo, and you're all set. If you have a selection, it duplicates the selection.

Comment: Usually using shift+cursor, ctrl-c, ctrl-v. I select the same way i did in any other "norma" text editor: starting at first char in first line, down to first char of the first line after the last line i want to copy.

Line duplication is not what i need, i only made a minimal example where that would help :)